# showing there isn't such probability measure u such that un weakly converges to u

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$u_{n}=Uniform[0,n]$ where $u_{n}([a,b])=(b-a)/n$.

I'm trying to show there isn't such probability measure $u$ such that $u_{n}\Rightarrow u$.

Using proof by contradiction,

Suppose there exists such a distribution $u$, then by the definition of weak convergence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_{n}((-\infty,x])=u((-\infty,x])$

I want to show such $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_{n}((-\infty,x])$ doesn't exist, but confused how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [This link will help you improve your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.8938).

Comment: @amWhy He's showed context though. He indicated an attempt to prove it by contradiction.

Comment: No, they copied a problem statement, and said "i want to show what the questions tells me to show," essentially.  *I have to clue* has a separate section for the OP.  Plus lots of other tips.  I am doing what all users should do to help new users: offering important links which will help them to be successful on math.se.  Where is their attempt to prove the problem statement by contradiction?  Do you see it?  I don't see it.  Too much verbage, no substance nor context.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily argue that $u_n(K)\to 0$ for any compact set $K$. If it does not seem obvious, you can first show that $u_n(I)\to 0$ for any interval $I$.

Now suppose $u_n$ converges to a probability measure $u$ weakly. Recall (Prove if you haven't already) that any probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is tight. In other words, there exists a compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $u(K)\ge \frac{1}{2}$. But this is not possible (Why?).