# show that uniform probability measure on $\{1,2,...n\}$ does not converge weakly to any probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $P_n$ be uniform probability measure on $\{1,2,...n\}$ show that $P_n$ does not converge weakly to any probability measure.

To prove this by contradiction, assume $P_n\Rightarrow P$ where, $P$ is some probability measure. Then, by definition of weak convergence, for any continuous bounded function, $f$
$$\int fdP_n\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int fdP.$$
Let us take $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]\backepsilon f(x)=x$, which is continuous and bounded. Then, $$\int f(x)P_n(dx)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n+1}{2}\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$$
but, $$\int f(x)P(dx)=\int xP(dx)\overset{\text{why?}}{<}\infty.$$
Is the attempt correct. If it is, I am not very clear about why the second integral is always finite. Please help.

*Note. There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337802/562589) but it doesn't clear my doubt.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this by contradiction, assume $P_n \Rightarrow P$ where $P$ is some probability measure. Then, by definition of weak convergence, for any continuous bounded function $f$,

$$\int f(x) \, dP_n(x) \rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f(x) \, dP(x)$$

Let us take $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x$, which is continuous and bounded. Then,

$$\int f(x) \, dP_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n+1}{2} \rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty} \infty$$

But,

$$\int f(x) \, dP(x) = \int x \, dP(x) < \infty$$

To answer your question, the second integral is always finite because $P$ is a probability measure. By definition, a probability measure on a measurable space (in this case, $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra) is a non-negative measure that assigns a total measure of 1 to the entire space. Therefore, for any measurable set $A$, $P(A)$ is a non-negative real number less than or equal to 1.

In this case, since $f(x)=x$ and $x\in[0,1]$, we have

$$\int f(x) \, dP(x) = \int x \, dP(x) \leq \int_{[0,1]} dP(x) = 1$$

Thus, the integral is finite.

Answer (score 5):

$P_n$ is not concentrated on $[0,1]$ so you have to consider bounded continuous functions on the whole line.

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. There is a  continuous function $f$ such that $0 \leq f(y)\leq 1$ for all $y$, $f(y)=1$ for $y \leq x$ and $f(y)=0$ for $y >x+1$.  We have $P(-\infty,x] \leq \int fdP=\lim \int fdP_n \leq \frac {k_n} n$ where $k_n$ is the number of positive integers less than or equal to $x+1$. This gives $P(-\infty,x]=0$ for all $x$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand how this translates to $\int fdP_n$ not converging to $\int fdP$. So, our function $f=N_n$ which is bounded and continuous over the real line. What after?

Comment: @zaira I had used an equivalent definition of weak convergence.  I have now  changed the proof so as to use your definition of weak convergence.

Answer (score 2):

For a sequence of random variables(or probability measures $\mu_{n}$), there exists  a weakly convergent subsequence if and only if the sequence is tight. That is given $\epsilon>0$ , there exists an $M>0$ such that $\sup_{n\geq 1}\mu_{n}([-M,M]^{c})<\epsilon$ . Tightness is what characterizes precompactness in the space of probability measures(with Levy/Prokhorov metric)

It's clear that given any natural number $M\geq0$  , you have $\displaystyle\mu_{n}([-M,M]^{c})\geq \sum_{k=M+1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-M}{n}=1-\frac{M}{n}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq 2M$  . Thus this sequence cannot possibly be tight.